# Shuffle "PASSWORD-HASHERS" every hour Django

Tags: python, django, hash, password-encryption

Im trying to make a website with Django, and what i saw that if you change the default django hasher, it will automatically change it for the user who logs in too. For example, you have an user password encoded with Bcrypt, and you change in Django settings file the hasher with Argon. Next time the user logs in, Django will automatically change the password encriptaion with Argon. Basically what i want to do is change the hasher automatically every hour.

I tried with threads but the only problem is that i need to restart the server to apply the new hasher.

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
]

def randomizeHasher():
    global PASSWORD_HASHERS
    while(True):
        hasher = PASSWORD_HASHERS
        random.shuffle(hasher)
        PASSWORD_HASHERS = hasher
        time.sleep(20)


t = threading.Timer(0,randomizeHasher)
t.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

> You shouldn’t alter settings in your applications at runtime

Source: [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime)

That being said, **consider the following** (not able to test it atm)

1. Create a management command that alters the settings using:

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(PASSWORD_HASHERS=randomized_hashers)
```

2. Create a cron job to run the command every hour

Comment: With Crontab? I've tried but i dont understand how to use it

Comment: Check: https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux